# Multiple Get by Id methods in one controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to apply multiple Get method in mvc controller. I've two get method with getting data by id, is there a way to configure it? I'm using .net core

Here route configuration:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

And two method from controller:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IEnumerable<Answer> GetAnswersByTestId(int id)
    => _userQuizRepository.GetTestByAnswerId(id);

[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IEnumerable<Test> GeTestById(int id) => _userQuizRepository.GetTestById(id);
```

And in angular I getting access by the follow url:

```
function myFunc(id) {
    return $http.get('/api/mycontroller/' + id);
}
```

Comment: You expected `/api/mycontroller/{id}` to work for both routes?

Comment: @Tim, yep if it offcourse possible

Comment: :)  How does the mvc framework supposed to know which one are you expecting ?

Comment: How would you expect your server to know the difference?  `/api/mycontroller/1`  -- there is no way for your server to know what you're asking for.

Comment: @Shyju maybe via attribute [Route] or [RoutePrefix] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you keep both of your Son's name as "**Scott**" and you want to give a candy to one Scott (*because you like him more*). You call "***Scott come here***", What is going to happen ? you think the correct Scott will only come ?

In short, You cannot have 2 methods with the same route pattern.

I suggest you create two unique route definitions which is more readable.

```
[HttpGet("test/{id}/answers")]
public IEnumerable<Answer> GetAnswersByTestId(int id){}     

[HttpGet("test/{id}")]
public IEnumerable<Test> GeTestById(int id) {}
```